# Check if the SD Card is available

Tags: blackberry

My application need to download some files to cache.
but i wanted to check if the user have SDcard installed so i can save files there instead of the device memory. i used this code :

```java
  String SDexist = "file:///SDCard/";

  fconnSD = (FileConnection) Connector.open(SDexist,Connector.READ);

  if(!fconnSD.exists())
  { 
      FileDire = "file:///store/home/user/catch/";
  } else
  {
      FileDire = "file:///SDCard/BlackBerry/catch/";
  }
```

but it's not working, it allways looks for SD card and not saving files in device memory even if the SD card is not available. Any ideas?

Comment: Probably the `"file:///SDCard/"` is just the folder that the SD card gets mounted on. Maybe use another API call, or find a file that is always on the SD card.

Comment: @owlstead You're rightm it's just a mounted dir. i used another method, read `FileSystemRegistry.listRoots()` and search if sdcard string exists in the root. It works now, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved, i used `FileSystemRegistry.listRoots();`
And read root elemnts, if sdcard exsits then the SD card should be installed.